# Displaying Hebrew text in a console

Tags: windows, fonts, console, language-features

How to add a new font to the console (win7), and where can I find the right font in hebrew?

I've already checked [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q247815), but it didn't help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download [console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/). It's an alternative console for Windows.

Answer (score 28):

There is another alternative console - [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) (open source too). It may be more useful for you.

I'm an author of this utility.

Here is a short list of its advantages: proportional and bdf fonts support, ANSI X3.64 and Xterm 256 colors, run simple GUI apps in tabs, text search in console, configurable status bar, optional settings (e.g. pallette) for selected applications...

Answer (score 3):

In case you just want it for short testing purposes while debugging, just use [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) that does support unicode (tested with heb chars only).
This will enable you to get some sort of output while debugging the program.

Comment: Note that you will need to monitor the Output window in Visual Studio (View -> Output), as these lines will not show up in the Console Application window.

Comment: @EladNava I've emphasized that fact in my answer.